# Creating a new contract specifying a sender and value with factory pattern

Tags: solidity, dapps

I am using a factory pattern to deploy its children contracts here.

The child contract has a constructor as followed:

```
  constructor (
    string memory _potName,
    uint _duration,
    uint _minStake,
    PotType _potType
  )
  public payable { 
    require(msg.value >= _minStake); 
    ... 
  }
```

The factory contract create the child contract as:

```
  function createLotteryPot(
    string memory potName, uint duration, uint minStake,
    LotteryPot.PotType potType
  ) public payable returns(LotteryPot) {
    LotteryPot newContract = new LotteryPot({ _potName: potName,
      _duration: duration, _minStake: minStake, _potType: potType });
    ...
  }
```

My questions are:

1. In the factory contract, how can I pass the `msg.value` to the children contract? This is a requirement that during child contract creation, the owner also need to commit some ethereum.
2. How can I pass the `msg.sender` to the children contract to specify it is the owner instead of the contract? I understand I can pass in an additional parameter `msg.sender`. Just wonder is there a cleaner way to do it?

Thanks a lot for input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the first question you can send value like this:

```
LotteryPot newContract = (new LotteryPot).value(amount)({ _potName: potName,
      _duration: duration, _minStake: minStake, _potType: potType });
```

Secondly, for sending the `msg.sender` you can change the signature as:

```
constructor (
    string memory _potName,
    uint _duration,
    uint _minStake,
    PotType _potType,
    address sender
  )
  public payable { 
    require(msg.value >= _minStake); 
    ... 
  }
```

and later on when calling the constructor from factory you can pass the sender as parameter like so:

```
LotteryPot newContract = (new LotteryPot).value(amount)({ _potName: potName,
      _duration: duration, _minStake: minStake, _potType: potType, sender: msg.sender });
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. 

Also, I am using [openzeppelin `Ownable` library](https://docs.openzeppelin.org/docs/learn-about-access-control.html#ownership-ownablesol). Eventually, in child contract, I do `if (tx.origin != msg.sender) { transferOwnership(tx.origin) }`. In case someone else come across this same situation.

Comment: You are my life saver today :) Thank you Abdullah